# Is it possible to configure docker image name/tag for Quarkus build inside build.gradle (instead of passing properties)

Tags: gradle, quarkus

To configure the built image I can use properties mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#container-image-options, however they require me to pass them when I invoke the build e.g.

```
./gradlew clean build \
    -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true \
    -Dquarkus.container-image.tag=latest
```

Is there a way to configure these values in `build.gradle` / surrounding properties, in a fashion similar to what [bmuschko](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/api/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/tasks/image/DockerBuildImage.html#images) / jib plugins provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky way by simply doing the same thing that `-D` does:

```
System.setProperty("quarkus.container-image.build", "true")
System.setProperty("quarkus.container-image.tag", "potato")
```

put inside `build.gradle`, but it does not look like proper configuration like with bmuschko / jib plugins.